# How can I reproduce the gllamm() Stata function in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, stata, multilevel-analysis, gllamm

I'm currently working in a project, where I replicate a project that has been conducted with Stata. I, however, work with R.

The task is to estimate a multi level logit model. In Stata, the project was conducted with the `gllamm` package and its function.

My problem is now, that I'm unable to replicate what the `gllamm` function does in R. So far I used the `glmer()` function from the `lme4` package.

Here's an [example data set](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vmg23539vrx8ssn/AAAyRy88dfpy4knqfqfXPNZza?dl=0) and these are the respective code snippets:

Stata:

```
gllamm y z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 ///
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7,  ///
i(rank) family(binomial) link(logit)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

And R:

```
library(haven)
library(lme4)

# Data
data <- read_dta("data.dta")

# Model with converence warning:
mod1 <- glmer(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + 
                x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + 
                (1 | rank), 
             family = "binomial",
             data = dataw)

summary(mod1)

# Model with different maximizer:
mod2 <- glmer(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + 
                x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + 
               (1 | rank), 
              family = "binomial",
              control=glmerControl(optimizer="nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE),
             data = dataw)
summary(mod2)
```

Here is the `summary(mod2)` output:

[image]

Unfortunately, one can see that the results differ in respect to the size and certainty of the estimates.

- Is there a possibility to get (approximately) the same results in R?
- What does `gllamm` do differently than `glmer`?
- Additional question: In a possible solution, is there an argument that would fit the `pweight()` argument of the `gllamm` function as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package that fits the same model using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature rule by default, e.g.,

```
library("GLMMadaptive")
library("haven")

dataw <- read_dta("data.dta")

fm <- mixed_model(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + 
                      x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7,
                  random = ~ 1 | rank, family = binomial(),
                  data = dataw, iter_EM = 0)

summary(fm)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is way closer to the original results. Sorry for the late "acceptance" of your answer. Is there a way to include weights in the formula?

Comment: Currently it is not yet available to include weights.